# Probability of children being girls

Tags: probability

Assume that the probability for a new born baby being a boy is $0,515$. Determine the probability that, given a family with $4$ children,

(a) every child is a girl,
(b) at least three children are girls,
(c) at least two childen are girls.

Yet, I have only managed to deal with (a). I guess in all of these cases, we have to work with the binomial distribution. When the probability for a baby being a boy is $0,515$, then the probability for a baby being a girl is $0,485$. Since every child is supposed to be a girl, we calculate

$4 \choose 4$$(0,485)^4(0,515)^0$.

So, what about (b) and (c)? I think that we have to work with the binomial coefficient $4 \choose 4$ again, but I don't know how to calculate the rest. Do I simply have to adjust the exponents here?

Comment: Since you already know what is probability of 4 children being girls, you just need to calculate 3 of them being girls and add the two to get b). And similar strategy works for c)

Comment: Can you elaborate this further? I understand what you want me to do, but I don't see the concept behind it.

Comment: $P(\text{at least 3 are girls})=P(\text{4 girls})+P(\text{3 girls})$, and $P(\text{at least 2 are girls})=P(\text{at least 3 girls})+P(\text{2 girls})$

Comment: Ah, I get it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say you have $n $ kids and the probability of one being a girl is $p $.

What are the odds of you having $k $ girls, with $k \leq n $?

Well, you pick $k $ kids, and the probability of them being girls is $p^k $. The probability of the $n-k $ left being boys is $(1-p)^{n-k} $, and you have ${n\choose {k}} $ ways of choosing the initial $k $ girls thus $P 
(\text {Having k girls}) = {n\choose {k}}\cdot p^k\cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$

So if you want $P(\text {Having at least k girls}) = P(X\geq k) $

where $X$ is the number of girls you have. Because you know $X \leq 4$ you can explicitly write that probability as a sum of probabilites. For example, $P(X \geq 3) = P(X = 3) + P(X = 4) $.

All tou have to do now is plug in your constants.